# How to pass an ArrayList as parameter in SOAP function?

Tags: android, web-services, serialization, soap, arraylist

I am developing an Android application and I need to pass an ArrayList as an argument to a SOAP function which provides a web service. This is the code I use :

```
public boolean addToCart(String username, ArrayList<String> itemsSelected, ArrayList<Integer> idsSelected) throws ServerOfflineException {

    String METHOD_NAME = "addToCart";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "\"" + NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME + "\"";

    try {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo usernameInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        usernameInfo.setName("arg0");
        usernameInfo.setValue(username);

        PropertyInfo itemsInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        itemsInfo.setName("arg1");
        itemsInfo.setValue(itemsSelected);

        PropertyInfo idsInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        idsInfo.setName("arg2");
        idsInfo.setValue(idsSelected);

        request.addProperty(usernameInfo);
        request.addProperty(itemsInfo);
        request.addProperty(idsInfo);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        String responseData = response.toString();

        if (responseData.equals("true")){
            return true;
        }
        else if (responseData.equals("false")){
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Error:" , e.getMessage());
        if (e instanceof SocketException) {
            throw new ServerOfflineException("Server Offline");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I get an error that **the ArrayLists cannot be serialized**. Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: use json for passing data

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Shubham!

Comment: PropertyInfo stringArrayPropertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        stringArrayPropertyInfo.setName("attributes");
        stringArrayPropertyInfo.setValue(param);
        stringArrayPropertyInfo.setType(param.getClass());
        request.addProperty(stringArrayPropertyInfo);

Here params is serialized json string

Comment: Does PropertyInfo implements Serializable? Use simple array instead of ArrayList.

Comment: Can you post a exemple? I'm with the same problem